# is there any disadvantage using hibernate query.settimeout() method

Tags: performance, hibernate, jdbc

we are planning to implement [setTimeout()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Transaction.html#setTimeout%28int%29) for all our hibernate queries.

In our application, a few of the queries take a long time.  We would like to specify an explicit timeout for these queries.

Are there any issues with this approach?  Or is there any better way to set timeout ?

I understand that there may be opportunities to tune the queries on the server side.  At the moment, however, we are looking exclusively for a client-side solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout()` method you linked to is not a timeout on a query. It's a timeout on the whole transaction. I fail to see how it's a client-side solution.

I think you're looking for [Query.setTimeout()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setTimeout%28int%29).